# Как добавить на сайт вот такой плеер?

Tags: html, css

Я так понимаю этот плеер добавляется тегом video, но у меня почему-то ничего не появляется. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Для этого используются плагины. Например jPlayer http://jplayer.org/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно использовать JavaScript
Вот простой пример:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <style>
    .player {
      width: 500px;
      height: 280px;
    }

    .player video {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }

    .cnt {
      margin-top: -50px;
      width: 100%;
      background: red;
      transition: 0.3s;
    }

    .player:hover .cnt {
      margin-top: -6px;
    }
    </style>
    <div class="player">
      <video id="video1" width="420">
        <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
      <div class="cnt">
        <button onclick="playPause()">Play/Pause</button>
        <button onclick="makeBig()">Big</button>
        <button onclick="makeSmall()">Small</button>
        <button onclick="makeNormal()">Normal</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script>
    var myVideo = document.getElementById("video1");

    function playPause() {
        if (myVideo.paused)
            myVideo.play();
        else
            myVideo.pause();
    }

    function makeBig() {
        myVideo.width = 560;
    }

    function makeSmall() {
        myVideo.width = 320;
    }

    function makeNormal() {
        myVideo.width = 420;
    }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

На HTML и CSS описываете стили плеера а затем вешаете скрипт. 
Если не сильны в JavaScript можно воспользоваться плагинами вроде jPlayer.
Хотя на чистом JS не так сложно это сделать:

```
var player = document.getElementById("video"); 
player.pause(); // Пауза
player.currentTime = 0; // Установка текушего времени
```

Более подробно c тегом video можете ознакомиться в [документации](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/video)